# Pandas groupby each value from a column

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have my dataset looking like this:

[image]

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"title":["movie1","movie2","movie3","movie4","movie5","movie6","movie7"],"genres":["Childrens Comedy","Comedy Drama","Western","Comedy Action","Action Childrens","Drama","Drama"],\
    "rating":[3,4,1,2,5,4,2],"user_id":[1,1,4,2,2,3,5], "gender":["F","F","F","M","M","M","M"]})
```

I would like to get the count of ratings given of each gender for each movie genre separately.

Expected output:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6PTV.png]

In the expected output we group by gender and want to count how many times each gender gave a rating in the specific movie genre (even if a movie has more movie genres).

Code until now but does not give the right output:

```
df.groupby(['genre','gender']).agg({"rating":"count"})
```

It doesn't give the right output as it groups only the genres that are fully the same. In that case only movie6 and movie7 will yell the correct results.

How do I group by each value in the genre column? I do not want to one hot encode them, as I already tried but the movie genres are so many in the real dataset that it simply doesn't work.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with reassing back to same column and [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), then get counts by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and add `0` for missing combinations by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) trick:

```
df1 = (df.assign(genres = df['genres'].str.split())
         .explode('genres')
         .groupby(['genres','gender'])["rating"]
         .size()
         .unstack(fill_value=0)
         .stack()
         .sort_index(level=[1,0], ascending=[False, True])
         .reset_index(name='count')
         )
print (df1)
      genres gender  count
0     Action      M      2
1  Childrens      M      1
2     Comedy      M      1
3      Drama      M      2
4    Western      M      0
5     Action      F      0
6  Childrens      F      1
7     Comedy      F      2
8      Drama      F      1
9    Western      F      1
```

Comment: it works but only until some extend. It gives me the count for all the different combinations of movie genres. I would like to have the count for each movie genre (for Action how many, for Comedy how many etc.) Output from this:

Comment: genres gender  count
0                                                      F      2
1                                                      M      8
2                                          Action      F    132
3                                          Action      M    747
4                                Action Adventure      F    334
5                                Action Adventure      M   1198
6    Action Adventure Animation Childrens Fantasy      F      6
7    Action Adventure Animation Childrens Fantasy      M      6

Comment: @Rulli - Sorry, answer was already edited with `(df.assign(genre = df['genre'].str.split()).explode('genre')`

Comment: hmm, maybe I'm doing something wrong but it still gives me the answer for all the different combinations of movie genres present. I want the count for each single movie genre, not the combined ones.

Comment: @Rulli - i cannot test data, because picture, is possible text version of input data sample?

Comment: sorry, yes I added it. Thank you very much!